# How to get a inherited object member from a list with lambda expression

Tags: c#, list, lambda, casting, inherited

My question is how do I have to make an object cast in a lambda expression from a `List<ExportData>` so that I can directly access the member `AddressByte` from `class CyclicData`?

Please do not describe any solutions without lambda, that I have already done. My question is if this is possible with lambda in one line of code?

```cs
    public class ExportData
    {
        public string Designation { get; set; }
    }

    public class StaticData : ExportData
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class CyclicData : ExportData
    {
        public string Block { get; set; }
        public string Typ { get; set; }
        public string AddressByte { get; set; }
        public string AddressBit { get; set; }
    }

        public void getMemberFromList()
        {
            List<ExportData> list = new List<ExportData>();
            list.Add(new CyclicData());
            list.Add(new StaticData());
            list.Add(new StaticData());

            //   get addressByte form Cyclic object with one line of code
            string addressByte = list.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(CyclicData)).FirstOrDefault().AddressByte; 
            //-> does not work because of missing cast to CyclicData;
        }
```

Does anyone have any idea if and how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string addressByte = list.OfType<CyclicData>().FirstOrDefault().AddressByte;
```

Assuming in the list there is always an instance of CyclicData, otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: "Assuming in the list there is always an instance of CyclicData, otherwise you'll get an exception.". no you won't get an exception with `OfType` that's with `Cast`.

Comment: @OusmaneD.the exception is for the AddressByte, not from the OfType

Comment: Alright, I see. that can be solved with a null conditional operator.

Comment: Good. I didn't use it because the original code is supposed to work the same.

Comment: OK. fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `OfType` (which filters the elements of `list`  based on `CyclicData`) followed with `FirstOrDefault`:

```
string addressByte = list.OfType<CyclicData>().FirstOrDefault()?.AddressByte;
```

or use `FirstOrDefault` followed with an explicit cast.

```
string addressByte = ((CyclicData)list.FirstOrDefault(x => x is CyclicData))?.AddressByte;
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best solution for me specifically, because of the null conditional test.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to do this kind of inheritance[it clearly violates LSP rule] and writing code to the abstraction.
To fool-proof this from a null exception

```
var addressByte = list.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(CyclicData)).FirstOrDefault();
if(addressByte !=null)
{
// do you logic here
}
```